# How to combine stdin and file for formatted output in sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

I need to find a single line of code, I think SED or AWK would be the best tools, to take two inputs (one stdin, one file) and combine them to output one formatted line to stdout.

stdin data: `20170607233000 wind0 180 1 2 3`

file data: `270`

output needed: `270 1 2 3`
(replace the 180 with 270 from file, drop the timestamp and wind0 "name")

I have this line of code:

```
awk ‘ { printf "%d %d %d %d", $7, $4, $5, $6 }’ - heading.txt
```

but it processes stdin and heading.txt and independent inputs and provides two outputs.

I also found this example of code, and it gets close to what I want but I don't understand how to format/reorder the output:

```
awk ’FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = $0; next } { print a[FNR""], $0 }'
```

---

Here's the context in case you care: This is for a weather station sitting on a (large) boat. The wind direction always reports relative to the boat, typically reporting North, but that's not accurate. The boat pivots on a single anchor point and always faces in to the wind. I have a magnetometer (compass) hooked to the RaspberryPi that is the weather station and reads the heading the boat is facing and writes it to a file via cron. This makes the boat in to a giant wind vane. I need to take the heading data from the file and replace the wind direction with the "real" value. The weather station code is nice enough to allow me to create a "virtual" gauge based on other gauges and insert code via a cgi script. The limitation is that the code has to be a single line that can be executed in the linux shell and return data via stdout.

Comment: Whoever wrote that sample of code containing `a[FNR""]` was extremely confused about awk syntax and semantics, forget you ever saw it. Watch your quotes btw - `’` and `‘` are not `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read from stdin and file unless you refer to stdin as `-` or `/dev/stdin` so first read in the value from the `file` and store it to a var. Then read the data from stdin and output:

```
$ echo 20170607233000 wind0 180 1 2 3 | awk 'NR==FNR{b=$1;next}{print b, $4,$5,$6}' file -
270 1 2 3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. If you want to see the results in action: https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KCADOBBI2

Comment: Cool, actual production solution. Usually it's just someone's homework.

Comment: Looking at that wind direction graph, maybe you should form a trend graph, place it in the middle and draw the scale around that. Now that the wind is from North, the dots are on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `sed`:

```
echo "20170607233000 wind0 180 1 2 3" | sed 'N;s/\n.*180//;' file -
```

Comment: This was real close, but still ran in to the same problem with the output on two lines instead of one. I ended up using the code in James Brown's answer below. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @mikeo It seems that your file ends with a newline, which you failed to specify.